# Why do I get 405 error when trying to use reddit API?

Tags: react-native, api, mobile, reddit, http-status-code-405

I am currently making a mobile app that fetch data from reddit API and display it on a remake of Reddit interface.

The application is made of multiple page the first being the login page, it use oauth 2.0 to retrieve a connection token and then navigate to another page where I try to get data about my reddit profile and display it.

The login page work as indented, I can connect to the reddit API and navigate to the next page but when I try to fetch any data from reddit API I got a *405* error code, sometime followed by an *500* error.

Here is the code for the backend of the second page :

```
const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    let token = route.params.token;

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [sub_count, setSubCount] = useState('');
    const [profile_img_url, setImgUrl] = useState('');
    const [date, setDate] = useState('');

    async function fetchRedditAPI() {
        var config = {
            method: 'set',
            url: 'https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        };
        axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
           console.log("----API DATA-----")
           console.log(response["data"])
           console.log("-----------------")
           let profile_img_url = response["data"]["icon_img"]
           setImgUrl(profile_img_url);
           let date = response["data"]["created_utc"]
           setDate(date);
           let username = response["data"]["display_name_prefixed"]
           setUsername(username);
           let sub_count = response["data"]["subscribers"]
           setSubCount(sub_count);
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
           console.log("GOT THE FOLLOWING ERROR :")
           console.log(error);
           console.log("------------------------")
       });
    }
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("fetching reddit API...");
        fetchRedditAPI();
    }, []);
```

The following error display in my terminal :

```
Request failed with status code 405
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:605:6 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Request failed with status code 500
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:605:6 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Any help would be precious, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)  error occurs when you try to access an endpoint using a request method that is not allowed. I assume it's because your request method is `set` instead of `get`?

Comment: Thank you, that was the indeed the problem, I changed `method: 'set'` wtih `method: 'get'` and it worked !